# Why do only some button icons display

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am trying to set a toolbar button image.  I have found various ways of defining button images, but none seem to work consistently.

Here are the ways I have found (either in documentation or on SO):

- In code (doesn't work at all for me [for toolbar buttons])

  ```
   public PXAction<DAC> action;
   [PXButton(CommitChanges = true, ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.ArrowRight)]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Action")]
   protected virtual void Action()
  ```
- In ASPX, in `Base Properties` > `Images` > `Normal` of the screen editor

  - `Normal` | `main@ArrowRight`
- In ASPX, in `Ext Properties` > `ImageKey` *and* `ImageSet` of the screen editor

  - `ImageKey` | `main`
  - `ImageSet` | `ArrowRight`

The ASPX options work for the `main` `ArrowRight` icon, but there are various other icons in the same sprite that I would like to use that do NOT work.  For instance, intellisense in VS suggests that `Relation` and `RelationF` are also in the `main` sprite, but these display as blank images.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I access something other than arrows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web font is contained in the `fonts` folder of the Acumatica web site on the web server. Install a local Acumatica web site if necessary.

Font folder example: C:\AcumaticaSites\YourWebsite\fonts

Open one of the fonts file. The file `acumatica-font-v1.svg` can be opened in a text editor.

You will notice `Relation` / `RelationF` are missing and `main-ArrowRight` is declared in the file:

```
<glyph unicode="&#xe90a;" glyph-name="main-ArrowRight, ac-arrow_forward" d="M448 134.4l262.4 262.4h-582.4v96h582.4l-262.4 275.2 64 64 384-384-384-384-64 70.4z" />
```

Check the mapping between the constant and the Unicode icon in  `Content\font-awesome.css` CSS file:

```
.main-ArrowRight:before {
  content: "\e90a";
}
```

You can also open the true type font `ttf` from the `fonts` folder and install it to view the icons in a font viewer.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to see the character name in Character Map?

Comment: No, use other font viewers and try the other font formats for more options. With CharMap, look up Unicode value in the bottom status bar. Encode Unicode value and look it up in SVG file, U+F01D encoded as &#xe90a;

Comment: Are all the ways I documented in my post still viable ways of setting icons, or has something changed?  Is there a recommended way?

Comment: I usually just search the ASPX and CS files for ImageKey, copy examples, test them and select the first one that achieves the desired result. My answer was more about  why some constants aren't mapped to actual icons.

Comment: ImageSet is just an alternative syntax, adding the set in the ImageKey property should achieve the same result. So it's really only one way to do it in that regard. You can also set custom images.

Comment: The last piece is mapping between icon Unicode character and the constant in CSS file 'Content\font-awesome.css'. I updated my answer with that.